# Time Series DataFrame. How to find rows that do not hav corresponding dates

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

So I have a dataframe with roughly 9,000 rows that tracked the weather for each day for most cities for a few years. However, some dates were not recorded in that time and the problem I am dealing with at the moment is to find those dates that are missing in my dataframe.

I wrote a sample code that would help me solve my problem by listing out the days for just one week between 4/14/2021 to 4/20/2021 where some days are missing but there are multiple entries of the same day.

```
dates = ['4/20/2021', '4/20/2021', '4/20/2021', '4/20/2021', '4/20/2021', '4/19/2021', '4/19/2021', '4/19/2021', '4/19/2021',
     '4/19/2021', '4/19/2021', '4/19/2021', '4/19/2021', '4/18/2021', '4/16/2021', '4/16/2021', '4/16/2021', '4/16/2021', 
     '4/14/2021', '4/16/2021', '4/16/2021', '4/16/2021', '4/16/2021']

d = {'date': dates}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.columns = ['date']
```

Now I need a way where I can identify dates that are missing for that week which is the 15th and 17th. Or 4/15/2021 and 4/17/2021.

One method I tried is to count the number of same dates that occur

```
given_days = (pd.to_datetime(df['date']).value_counts().rename_axis('date').reset_index(name='count'))
```

It worked for my sample code however, for my original dataframe with 9,000 rows, the dates I've tracked was from 1/1/2015 to 4/20/2021 which in total should come out to 1937 unique days but when I tried implementing this I got over 2,000 rows and it stopped at some time around 2019 which is really odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution,merge dataframe has indicator true or false indicating missing date or not

```
start = "2015-01-01"
end = "2021-04-20"

unique_dates = df["date"].unique()
all_dates = pd.date_range(start,end,freq='D')
or_df = pd.DataFrame({"dates":unique_dates})
cmp_df = pd.DataFrame({"dates":all_dates})
merge = pd.merge(cmp_df,or_df,on="dates",how="left",indicator=True)
```

Comment: I still get 2302 rows and theres a new column that says "both" for each row. However, it includes the start and end date whereas before my dates started somewhere past my initial date and ended before the end date

Comment: new column indicate whether both df had the same date or not.if left df had a record and not in right df,indicator should be _left_only

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date strings to proper datetimes

```
df["date"]  = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Then resample by 1 day and check the sums, missing days will have 0

```
>>> df.resample('1D', on="date").count()
            date
date
2021-04-14     1
2021-04-15     0
2021-04-16     8
2021-04-17     0
2021-04-18     1
2021-04-19     8
2021-04-20     5
```

And it we go further

```
>>> df.resample('1D', on="date").count().eq(0).query("date").index.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").values.tolist()
['04/15/2021', '04/17/2021']
```

If you have other columns, select `date` column only

```
>>> df[["date"]].resample('1D', on="date").count().eq(0).query("date").index.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").values.tolist()
['04/15/2021', '04/17/2021']
```

Comment: '\nunique_dates = weather_data[\'location_date\'].unique()\nall_dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=\'D\')\nor_df = pd.DataFrame({\'dates\': unique_dates})\ncmp_df = pd.DataFrame({\'dates\': all_dates})\n\nmerge = pd.merge(cmp_df, or_df, on="dates", how="left", indicator=True)\n\nmerge\n\n'

Comment: that was the output i got... i dont know why

Comment: @GirthyLampost can't really read that. Is your date column of datetime type? If so, can you select it with `df[['date']]` as in updated answer?